# How to pass data to Google Charts?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Charts for my ASP.NET website.  I want to include this on a page that loads and calculates the data for the addrows function.

After I calculate my counts I need for the graph how can I pass them to the script on the page from the code behind.  I am using VB.NET in visual Studio 2008.

How is the best way to pass the count data to the graph?

```
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Any good VB.Net examples?  I am trying to create the data with the code behind and then pass it to the chart.

Answer (score 1):

You should create Google DataTable class on server side, initialize it's instance with data and then store it to the JSON string, then assign that string it to the Google DataTable on client side, something like this :

C#

```
public string GoogleDataTableJson { get; private set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GoogleDataTable table = CreateAndFillGoogleDataTable();
  Serializer ser = new Serializer(typeof(GoogleDataTable);
  this.GoogleDataTableJson = ser.Serialize(table);
}
```

and then in JavaScript :

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<%= GoogleDataTableJson %>);
```

Or you can use .NET helper that can use .NET DataTable class to fill Google Visualization :

http://code.google.com/p/bortosky-google-visualization/

Comment: I get a error - "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.Module'."

Comment: don't have a clue, why you are serializing module ? You should create plain GoogleDataTable class on server that will have all properties as a real one and serialize that object